# Python scope between local and global

Tags: python

I have two samples:

One:

```
import math

def my_function():
    print(math.pi)
    math.pi = 3
    print(math.pi)

my_function()
```

Output:

```
3.141592653589793
3
```

Two:

```
a = 0

def my_function():
    print(a)
    a = 3
    print(a)

my_function()
```

Output:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`

So what is the difference between them? I thought both `math.pi` and `a` were global in this case and it should produce `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: Why do you think the first case should produce an error? Do you think `math.pi` is local to your function?

Comment: `math.pi` isn't a global variable. `math` is a global variable. `math.pi` is an attribute.

Comment: global variables need to be explicitly declared in a function using e.g. `global a` in your second case, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Comment: (Or at least, syntactically speaking, it's not a global variable. There are a few senses in which it would be considered a global variable, but not in this sense.)

Comment: So you both refer this as global attribute of math module, right? this mean `print(math.pi)` and `math.pi = 3` use the same `pi` attr from `math`. I first thought `math.pi` is a local var in my_fuction that `.` should be a refer to `math` instead produce a local var. Thanks.

Comment: @user2357112 : According to the FAQ I linked above, `a` would work fine as a global without being declared global, as long as it's not modified within the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do variable assignment within function the global variable would be ignored and won't be accessible within function execution, in sample with `math` lib you do not override name `math` itself, that's why it works. Snipped below would give you same error with math lib:

```
import math

def my_function():
  print(math.pi)
  math = 1

my_function()
```

You can use statement [global](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/global.html) before accessing variable, but if you will do any assignment later you will override global variable, **so it's better to ALWAYS  avoid doing that**.

```
import math


def my_function():
  global math
  print(math.pi)
  math = 1

print(math) # -> <module 'math' from ...    
my_function() # -> 3.14159265359
print(math) # -> 1
```

Comment: Woa, that's too much, `math` in `import math` is a var also? I didn't know that.

Comment: @TuyenPham kind of, `math` is the the global reference to the module object, so you can apply `global` to modify it within function, however you will loose your reference to your math module object stored in memory

Comment: If we add `print(math.pi)` at the end of your code, `AttributeError` will occur - that is expected. `math` 's memory location is destroyed completely because of `global` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In the first function, the variable is `math`, not `math.pi`. Since you're not assigning to `math`, it doesn't become a local variable. Assigning to an attribute of a variable is not the same thing as assigning to the variable itself.

If you changed the function to

```
def my_function():
    print(math.pi)
    math = 3
    print(math.pi)
```

you would get the same kind of error as in the second function:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'math' referenced before assignment

Comment: It produces empty output with your code. What is different assigning between var itself and an attr of a var?

Comment: The variable contains a reference to an object. The attribute is part of the object.

Comment: I don't know why you get empty output. Did you call the function?

Comment: Let's make it more specific about `scope`. In this case, because of `math.pi` that refer to math module - this is global and look for its attr - global too, So actually `math.pi` is a global reference that implicitly no `global` keyword there. And with Python there no kind of definition happens in local that has appearance `math.pi` because of `.` here is a reference operator in python. Do I understand right?

Comment: No, that's not correct. As you can see in my modified function, it becomes a local variable if you assign to it, and then you get an error when you try to access `math.pi`.

Comment: I see, redefine var `math`. `pi` is just a att of math.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered a few times on SO before.

A variable is local to a function if there's a statement assigning it inside that function.
In your instance `a = 3` defines `a` as local variable inside of your function. The first `print(a)` tries to access it, but it's not assigned a value yet.

That's why you see:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment.
```

The global instance created by `a = 0` plays no role here.